# Накопительный итог для агрегатной функции

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица столбцами `[modify_date]`, `[response_1]`, `[response_2]`, `[response_3]`,`[incident_id]`.

[image: **таблица**]

Таблица отображает дату опроса, оценки поставленные по 3 критериям и номер заявки по которой были поставлены оценки.

- `modify_date` - дата опроса
- `response_1-3` - оценки
- `incident_id` - номер заявки.

Задача состоит в следующем:

1. посчитать среднее значение всех оценок по неделям за квартал.
2. вывести историю изменения оценок по неделям за квартал.

Например, имеем средние оценки за:

- первую неделю квартала: 4.3
- вторую неделю квартала: 5
- третью неделю квартала: 3.2

Тогда должен получится результат

- первая неделя квартала: 4.3
- вторая неделя квартала: 4.65 ((4.3+5)/2))
- третья неделя квартала: 4.16 ((4.3+5+3.2)/3));

Вывел средние оценки по неделям, но как рассчитать накопительную функцию для агрегатной функции ума не приложу. Дополнительной проблемой стало то, что изменения необходимо отображать до сотых.

```
SELECT TOP (500) 
    concat(datepart(ww, surv_req.modify_date),  
            ',',
            MONTH(surv_req.modify_date)
      ) as [Неделя/Месяц],
    left(replace(cast(
       round((avg(surv_req.response_1*1.00) 
           + avg(surv_req.response_2*1.00) 
           + avg(surv_req.response_3*1.00))/3,2) 
       as char (9)),
    '.',','),4) as 'Оценка'
FROM surv_req
WHERE response_1 <>'0' 
     and surv_req.issued_date 
           between  
             (select dateadd(qq, datediff(qq, 0, GETDATE()), 0)) 
           and GETDATE()
GROUP BY month(surv_req.modify_date)
        ,datepart(ww, surv_req.modify_date)
```

[image: результат]

Заранее отмечу, что:

1. изменение с точки на запятую, в поле `Оценка` сделано специально, так как данный результат будет отправляться в систему построения графиков и точки она не распознает.
2. в принципе все манипуляции с результатом сделаны под систему построения графиков.

Немного подправил. Теперь как мне рассчитать накопительный итог?

SELECT     TOP (500) concat(datepart(ww, surv_req.modify_date) , ',',MONTH(surv_req.modify_date)) as [Неделя/Месяц],
 (avg(surv_req.response_1*1.00)+avg(surv_req.response_2*1.00)+avg(surv_req.response_3*1.00))/3 as 'Оценка'
FROM         surv_req INNER JOIN
                      incident ON surv_req.incident_id = incident.incident_id INNER JOIN
                      assyst_usr ON incident.inc_resolve_usr = assyst_usr.assyst_usr_id
                      where response_1 <>'0' and
surv_req.issued_date between  (select dateadd(qq, datediff(qq, 0, GETDATE()), 0)) and GETDATE()
GROUP BY month(surv_req.modify_date),datepart(ww, surv_req.modify_date)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Указывайте точно СУБД, включая версию. И создайте fiddle.

Comment: вы бы лучше сначала задачу решили, а потом уже манипуляции сверху навернули, если они нужны.